# Unable to fix "RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False." MAC M1 MPS GPU

Tags: macos, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

My MAC Pro has the latest MPS GPU. I'm trying to reproduce some results from a colleague who read a pickle file using a local NVIDIA GPU.

First, I ensured that my mps gpu is being used:

```
import torch
device = torch.device("mps") if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu"
```

Then I ran the following codes:

```
import pickle

with open('patient_notes_agg.pickle', 'rb') as df:
     patient_notes_agg = pickle.load(df)
patient_notes_agg.head()
```

I received the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

So I tried to follow the prompt and switch to use cpu instead of mps gpu, and I used the code below:

```
model = torch.load('patient_notes_agg.pickle', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
```

Unfortunately, I still received the same error.

To give more details:

MacOS Montery 12.3
chip Apple M1 Max

pytorch version '1.13.0'
Python 3.10.7

And I don't use conda environment.

I went through several posts with similar issues on stackoverflow, but unfortunately they didn't help. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work around the issue. Not utilizing my M1 GPU but using cpu instead by creating a reading function. Thanks to this [link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/pickle.load+from+gpu+device+to+cpu).

```
import io
import pickle

class CPU_Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if module == 'torch.storage' and name == '_load_from_bytes':
            return lambda b: torch.load(io.BytesIO(b), map_location='cpu')
        else: return super().find_class(module, name)


with open('patient_notes_agg.pickle', 'rb') as df:
     patient_notes_agg = CPU_Unpickler(df).load()
patient_notes_agg.head()
```